# Azure Function SendGrid

Tags: t-sql, azure, sendgrid, azure-functions, mass-emails

Hi I'm basically executing a query which returns x amount of emails  that exist on a specific day and I want to send an email to all of these emails using sendgrid's api here is my code - I am running into alot of errors listed below could anyone shed some light?

[code]

```
**#r "System.Data"
#r "SendGrid"

using System;
using System.Data;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using SendGrid;

        private SqlConnection conn = null;
        private SqlDataAdapter da = null;
        private SqlCommandBuilder cb = null;
        private DataSet ds = null;
        private String location = null;

public void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        string connStr = "Data Source=sdc-hwsb.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=SDC-HotelWSBooking;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sdchwsb;Password=Trivago17!;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();
        string query = "SELECT email FROM dbo.test_bookings2 WHERE startDate = @startDate";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
        int k = 0;
        int f = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
        while (f > 0 & k < f)
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            String Email = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[k]);
            Run1(Email,message);
            k++;

        }

    }


    public static void Run1(string email, out Mail message)
{
      message = new Mail
        {        
        Subject = "Azure news"          
    };
var personalization = new Personalization();
// change to email of recipient
personalization.AddTo(new Email(email));   

Content content = new Content
{
    Type = "text/plain",
    Value = "DD"
};
message.AddContent(content);
message.AddPersonalization(personalization);
```

}

```
**
```

I Am getting errors reffering to the Message object sendgrid is using such as:

```
    2017-09-25T18:50:37.754 Function started (Id=067b32b9-7bc3-47ca-9f32-b8b92c3b57e9)
2017-09-25T18:50:37.770 Function compilation error
2017-09-25T18:50:37.770 run.csx(38,28): error CS0103: The name 'message' does not exist in the current context
2017-09-25T18:50:37.807 Exception while executing function: Functions.TimerTriggerCSharp1. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Script compilation failed.
2017-09-25T18:50:37.948 Function completed (Failure, Id=067b32b9-7bc3-47ca-9f32-b8b92c3b57e9, Duration=196ms)
```

Answer (score 2):

As Mike S mentioned about sending multiple emails via use an `ICollector`, I checked the official document about [SendGrid output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid) and did not find any sample, then I followed the code sample from [Queue output sample in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue) to test this feature as follows:

**run.csx**

```html
#r "SendGrid"

using System;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log, ICollector<Mail> mails)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        Mail message = new Mail()
        {
            Subject = $"Hello world from the SendGrid C# TimerTrigger!"
        };

        var personalization = new Personalization();
        personalization.AddTo(new Email("the-email-address-of-recipient"));  

        Content content = new Content
        {
            Type = "text/plain",
            Value = $"Hello world!{i}"
        };

        message.AddContent(content);  
        message.AddPersonalization(personalization); 
        mails.Add(message);
    }
}
```

**function.json**

```html
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "sendGrid",
      "name": "mails",
      "apiKey": "sendgrid-apikey",
      "direction": "out",
      "from":"<the-email-address-of-sender>"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Additionally, for creating Functions class library project via VS2017, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library) about SendGrid output.

Answer (score 0):

Some of those errors are compilation errors - fix those first. For example, you're missing a ')' on line 28.

You can also author functions in Visual Studio - which will give you the power of a real IDE with C# intellisense and error checking. That would catch the errors above. That's useful as soon as your functions are non-trivial. Check out details here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/08/14/azure-functions-tools-released-for-visual-studio-2017-update-3/

The SendGrid binding should be on your Run() function.

```
public void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log, out Mail message)
```

And then Run1 is just an internal helper to generate the message.

If you need to send multiple messages, use ICollector / IAsyncCollector. That has an 'add' method.

Comment: I fixed them../ @MikeS

Comment: Not all of them :) It's still telling you about C# compilation errors in your code.  The usage of 'message' of line 38 is illegal.

Comment: that's the sendgrid object.. this is the documentation which I'm using to bind it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid

Comment: As you have it, 'message' is a parameter on Run1(). There's no 'message' variable define in Run(). You may want to use the VS tooling link above - the IDE will be very helpful here.
The bindings here only apply to the Run() method, not to Run1().  
I think what you really want is to move the sendgrid binding (message) onto Run() , and then you can call helpers from there.

Comment: So I renamed run1() to Run() but what do I name the main method too? I'm still getting a message couldnt be found error

Comment: You're having problems with writing C# code that compiles (not with Functions). I'd strongly suggest using the VS IDE to write this since that will help you with the compiler errors.

Comment: How am I suppose to use bindings in VS though? I feel theres something wrong with my binding